# Codeigniter preg_replace() - Compilation failed: message

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am Posting 5 pages of docx data from cleditor codeigniter ajax. While data passes to the controller it gives warning  message:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: regular expression is too large 
   at offset 65439

Filename: core/Security.php

Line Number: 641"
```

and no data posted on controller side like:

```
// displays nothing
echo $messageText=trim($this->input->post('composeMessage', TRUE));
```

I tried to set FALSE global_xss_filtering in config.php

```
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;
```

but it did not work.

Comment: If the input is way too long, you might break it into pieces and run subsequently.

Comment: yes that is the way, but there may be something better using codeigniter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem comes due to some limitations in CI post function. You can use PHP $_POST array variable to handle this issue.

e.g.

$your_variable = $_POST['posted_data'];

Answer (score 0):

You can increasing the PCRE backtrack and recursion limit may fix the problem in `php.ini` file `pcre.backtrack_limit` and `pcre.recursion_limit`, but will still fail when the size of your data hits the new limit. (doesn't scale well with more data)

```
<?php 
  // essential for huge PCREs
 ini_set("pcre.backtrack_limit", "23001337");
 ini_set("pcre.recursion_limit", "23001337");
 // imagine your PCRE here...
?>
```

you can optimize your code and possibly split your complex expression into "parts" and move some logic to PHP.

Comment: AFAIU, the complex expression came from the user input.